# Angular 1.5 when select all in input checkbox, value won't bind to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Hi I am using https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/ to bind data from a checkbox to the model. When a user selects a checkbox it successfully binds data. However, I need the options to also "select all" I have followed the instructions in the documentation and have tried mapping all the value in the array so when the user "selects all" all the values are binded into the model. Instead of that happening I get an array with value of null. Here is how the flow works

1)`init()` function is called returning data when the user loads the application

2)user selects an air_date

3)user gets syscode data return after ng-options `getSyscodes()` is called

4)A user can select multiple syscodes

5)User can "select all" this is where my issue is, when I call `selectAll()`, instead of returning every value in array, the array returns as "null" and I can't make a call to the API. 
I would appreciate any suggestions thanks!
Here is my HTML

Array Structure of Every Object

`{syscode:1233,readable_name: "MTV"}`

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <pre>Selected Model: {{rc.selections.syscode}} </pre>
    <label>Syscode</label>
    <!-- <select class="form-control" ng-options="syscode.readable_name for syscode in rc.dropdowns.syscodes" ng-model="rc.selections.syscode" ng-disabled="rc.dropdowns.syscodes.length === 0">
                                            </select> -->



  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:214px;height:33px;font-size:15px;margin-left:-16px;"><i class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="width:1em;"></i></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" ng-click="rc.selectAll()"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Select All</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md" ng-click="rc.unselectAll()"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>Unselect All</button>

    <li ng-repeat="value in rc.dropdowns.syscodes">
      <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="rc.selections.syscode" checklist-value="value.syscode" ng-checked="rc.selections.checked" />&nbsp;{{value.readable_name}}</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

And Controller

```
ReportsController.$inject = ['ReportService','$window', '$q'];
function ReportsController(ReportService, $window, $q){
  //Sorting Values
  var ctrl = this;

  //Initial State Values
  ctrl.results = [];
  ctrl.pageDone = false;
  ctrl.loading_results = false;
  ctrl.search_enabled = false;
  ctrl.searching = false;


  //Initial data arrays
  ctrl.dropdowns = {
    air_dates:[],
    syscodes:[],
    syscodeArray:[]
  };

  ctrl.test = null;
 //Data binding objects
  ctrl.selections = {
    air_date:null,
    checked: null,
    syscode:null,
    getAll: false
  };



  //Get Syscodes
  ctrl.selectSyscode = function(){
    ctrl.search_enabled = true;
    ctrl.dropdowns.syscodes = [];
    ctrl.dropdowns.syscodeArray = [];
    ReportService.getSyscodes(ctrl.selections).then(function(response){

      ctrl.dropdowns.syscodes = response.data;
      //This line below enables select all in UI
      ctrl.dropdowns.syscodeArray.push(response.data);
      console.log("SyscodeArray", ctrl.dropdowns.syscodeArray);
    });
  };

  // Select All Logic
ctrl.selectAll = function(){
var newitems = [];
angular.forEach(ctrl.dropdowns.syscodes, function(syscode) {
  ctrl.selections.checked = 1;
  newitems.push(syscode.syscode);
});

ctrl.selections.syscode = newitems;

}

  // Unselect All
  ctrl.unselectAll = function(){
    angular.forEach(ctrl.dropdowns.syscodeArray, function(user) {
      ctrl.selections.checked = 0;
    });
    ctrl.selections.syscode = [];
    }



  //Search Logic by Syscode and Air_Date
  ctrl.search = function () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    if (ctrl.search_enabled) {
      ctrl.searching = true;
      ctrl.error = false;
      ctrl.sort_by = {
        col: 'market',
        reverse: true
      };
      ctrl.filters = undefined;

      ReportService.getAssets(ctrl.selections).then(function (response) {
        ctrl.results = response.data;
        console.log("It worked!!!",response.data);
        ctrl.searched_once = true;
        ctrl.searching = false;
        defer.resolve('searched');

      }, function (error) {
        defer.reject('search-error');
        ctrl.error = true;
        ctrl.searching = false;
        ctrl.error_data = error;
      });
    } else {
      defer.resolve('no-search');
    }

    return defer.promise;
  };



 //Calls initial air dates
  var init = function(){
    ReportService.getAirDates().then(function(response){
      ctrl.dropdowns.air_dates = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
      ctrl.pageDone = true;
    });
  };
  init();
}


angular.module('command-center-app').controller('ReportsController', ReportsController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, I looped through the array and made a new array containing only "syscode". That array I assigned it ctrl.selections.syscode which is the model. This should be the correct answer

```
ctrl.selectAll = function(){
var newitems = [];
angular.forEach(ctrl.dropdowns.syscodes, function(syscode) {
  ctrl.selections.checked = 1;
  newitems.push(syscode.syscode);
});

ctrl.selections.syscode = newitems;

}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to select your own answer? I'm sure it's been long enough and you can do that now :)

Answer (score -1):

There is something wrong with your implementation i think. The library uses an array to handle the checked values in it. But i don't think you are doing that. Plus `ng-checked` should be there. So:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in rc.dropdowns.syscodes">
      <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="rc.selections.checked" checklist-value="value.syscode" />
      &nbsp;{{value.readable_name}}
</li>
```

In the controller:

```
  // Select All Logic
  ctrl.selectAll = function(){
    ctrl.selections.checked = [];
    angular.forEach(ctrl.dropdowns.syscodeArray, function(user) {
      ctrl.selections.checked.push( //iterate over all syscodes and push here
    });
  }

  // Unselect All
  ctrl.unselectAll = function(){
    ctrl.selections.checked = [];
  }
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: it says "push of undefined" in console when I try to execute this code

Comment: @hjm You have to iterate over your syscodes and push them. I just showed you a way.

Comment: I think someone should comment also on why downvoting something.